# Media Foundation: force a capture device to provide DirectX surfaces in a topology

Tags: video-capture, directx-9, ms-media-foundation, dxva

**Context**

I wrote an MFT that uses DXVA. It requires that input samples have a `IDirect3DSurface9` surface.

I use this MFT in a topology of 3 nodes:

- a source node that wraps a media source created from a capture device activator,
- a transform node that contains an instance of my MFT,
- an output node that contains an EVR.

I set the `MF_TOPOLOGY_DXVA_MODE` attribute to `MFTOPOLOGY_DXVA_FULL` and `MF_TOPOLOGY_HARDWARE_MODE` to `MFTOPOLOGY_HWMODE_USE_HARDWARE` on the topology, and when I start the media session I receive a D3DDeviceManager from inside my MFT.

**The Problem**

When input samples arrive on the MFT from inside the topology, they don't have a D3D surface attached to them (`MFGetService` with `MR_BUFFER_SERVICE` fails).

If I don't use a topology at all, and create a Source Reader from the same media source with a valid `MF_SOURCE_READER_D3D_MANAGER`, then the samples provided by the Source Reader have a D3D surface.

**The Question**

Is it possible to make the source node/capture media source in the topology produce samples with D3D surfaces ?

Comment: It might so happen that source reader does an internal copy from memory backed to surface backed sample for you. With no source reader you would be supposed to do it yourself.

Comment: So,  you can see that `Source Reader` is differ from `MediaSource`. `Source Reader` is more complex and can include decoder into the pipeline of extracting. Attribute MF_SOURCE_READER_D3D_MANAGER marks need using of Transform with MF_SA_D3D_AWARE supporting. Do you mark your MFT with MF_SA_D3D_AWARE attribute?

Comment: It seems you are both right: I ran my code using the `Source Reader` with `mftrace` and I can see that one or more MFTs are `CoCreateInstance`ed under the hood, especially the Video Processor MFT. It seems the `Source Reader` creates at least a Video Processor MFT to take care of the upload. I will try to do the same in the topology.

Comment: There is no reason that the input samples from the media source contains D3D surfaces. It's up to your dxva mft to provide them to EVR. The lonely reason would be that the video capture resides Inside the GPU, wich i suppose it is not.